# C++ How to check if json key exists using boost::json::value?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-json

Using `boost::json::value`, how do I check if a certain key exists?

The following code:

```
void checkMessage(std::string msg)
{
    boost::json::value json = boost::json::parse(payload);

    auto type = json.at("type").as_string();
    auto param1 = json.at("param1").as_string();
    auto param1 = json.at("param2").as_int64(); <<=== IT CHASHES HERE

    std::cout << "Received: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "type: " << type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "param1: " << param1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "param2: " << param2 << std::endl;
}
```

Crashes when trying to get the `param2` from my json data:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<std::out_of_range>'
  what():  out of range
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When the `param2` is missing:

```
std::string msg = "{\"type\", \"t1\", \"param1\": \"test parameter 1\"}";
```

Is there a way to check if the parameter exists before copying the json key value to the variable?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Does an exception get thrown? Maybe you can try catching the exvception to see if the key exists..

Comment: Please post working code (compiling) because there's entirely too many sloppy mistakes and illegal comments in there. The JSON isn't [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) either ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object::if_contains` method:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

#include <iostream>

void Check(::boost::json::object const & object, ::boost::json::string_view const name)
{
    ::boost::json::value const * const p_value{object.if_contains(name)};
    if (p_value)
    {
        ::std::cout << name << ": " << p_value->as_string();
    }
    else
    {
        ::std::cout << name << " is missing";
    }
    ::std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    ::boost::json::value json{::boost::json::parse(R"({"param1": "foo", "param3": "bar"})")};
    ::boost::json::object const & root{json.as_object()};
    Check(root, "param1");
    Check(root, "param2");
    Check(root, "param3");
}
```

> param1: "foo"
> param2 is missing
> param3: "bar"

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmABykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma24RqCkEAPTaCgIAdAiJifvYJhoAguub25h7B0cn55cMpwUSxudweT1eLzeDC2Xl2%2BzcTkGxEwrDBkJeADdUHh0Ds3AhMMgANYQEAgH6DMkXZwgVARbSEgg7NAMQZ7MwANh2dIZDlIOzJFIIVP%2BZKRwWAAH0MXhMAB3ZkCNnMNgzcEmADsVheO11AvJx0pIGpfhAGLEXk%2BLLZACpFaymYlpRbMJqLDzGVc8FRJSy6sEFBAVZg1RqACL7bXPPU7b07CBO83eEPgmNu1MxvVigjoMloLxM%2BHwnbBr5uYvmMwgdlmMvFxMugC0DyYCkl4qMEDVayjafDGd1lSUA72WpHMezuZQC0LB2LpaLBxrsYUOxYeAUqSMlcjI81EZ1WZAgyn%2Bdn5aXO4ArG4GDue%2Br%2B%2BjnsEmSwmMEu4/e0ehSKaUmlo7CabqCoawrGqKICJPUSgQAASpWEDpmYZgwcQrBcJW1aVvwqCVvylboawazYTWET1Du4ZqqhoYRg%2Bh66mBJz/qaHoOPabLmFyxDHAQbomlcraSuxBBfv2DHRnq%2BKEiSvGoAQhGocRLBYbRu6MXiBLEhA8mKTWKlmJW3Y/rqMk6XpSlofUJHGRprxPs8HBzLQnBXrwfgcFopCoJw5aWNYOyXIsyzsmsPCkMKXnOXMRIgFeGj6JwkgeZovC%2BRwvAKCAiVRVocxwLAMCINOLCJHQ0TkJQaBlRVMRbIYwBcByGiJVgMrLAAarKcoAPKJIwnARTQtAENE2UQBEaWkBEwT1AAnkNvCzcwxDzb19KMktpA1Wwgi9QwtCLdFpBYBEXjAG4Yi0Nl3C8Fg75GOIJ34MiDh4BimC3d5mCqISBYrN5r6VNNtB4BEGFrR4WDTQQxB4CwS1zFQBjAAo3Xyv1g13TIggiGI7BSLj8hKGo026K0BhGCg1jWPo4PZbAwYGicpCfTE3BxGYMU%2BYk1S3Y2jYnvsYamAFlhmBoOyNgA6td0sy79cNMArA3oIYjjIOl7Pw1gjNdm0jLpC4DDuJ4zT%2BKbkx9DErS5GkAgjC0SQpA7DDWyU/RjJURsCJ0wzm6MhvvX7QzdMEvSe7bthh07Axhx70xcHMwVLITLlualJ0ZTsqhxByjYcpIzJU8AOzNVcGiV/GuCECQYXJ7weU83FCVJRwKWkIjbeed5GVZTlkVpQVxUQEgM6JAWVUQDV5X0MQoSsCsecF0XOzAMgyDl2sVwRZg%2BBELrej8HjojiETJ8kyo6gnRTpByhhiRI%2B37mkL36WcL1BaT0yqBULn%2BdC7FwakYcuHJK7VwgB4Wq88G4zCbsPOYBImBYBiAbVyHdeDd0Su/HynAB65UQaQVuiUMFrCzn3fBQ9oozAzhwbmb9pr92oflOY7NUjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

Comment: That's weird code. Why did you use the initializer-list constructor to force `json` iinto an array? Please consider fixing, and also make things readable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57052ae7d7840d1b (Are you using AI to generate the code-snippet?)

Comment: Interesting! It seems that GCC and clang disagree about whether the initializer-list overload should take precedence. I'd expect it should, like GCC thinks: https://godbolt.org/z/698caMPqd Of course, you can still avoid the entire confusion by writing it as per my comment :)

Comment: @sehe I think gcc should not even consider selecting constructor overload (because no constructor should be invoked) and just materialize prvalue. https://godbolt.org/z/ecs51YaY8 It seems gcc has a general tendency to prefer initializer_list, i.e. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83264

Comment: I'm not talking about preferences, here. My personal preference agrees with you. However, the C++ standard mandates that initializer_list constructors take precedence when using uniform-initialization syntax (so `value{x}` instead of `value(x)`). I'm not 100%  convinced that applies here (there's a defaulted `storage_ptr` parameter trailing), but anyways, it's better to avoid the whole mess as long as compilers don't agree.

Comment: Filed an issue for awareness https://github.com/boostorg/json/issues/920

Comment: @sehe Also now i've realized that you've posted your answer suggesting `if_contains` prior to mine, making it kinda unnecessary. Yeah... But here you've wrote "also make things readable" and then post a really bizarre kind of code. copy-initialization everywhere? `auto  json = json::parse(R"...` - shadowing existing name with a different kind of entity while using old one in the same statement? That's probably one on the most evil things imaginable, on par with omitted curly braces after `if`. I have no idea where your ideas of "readable" come from, but they are certainly opposite to mine.

Comment: Let's not debate style. If your style is your taste, that's fine with me. I've never seen anyone consistently ::qualify toplevel namespaces. The conditional-with initializer was weird to me `if (T x = f(); x)` is exactly equivalent to the simpler c++03 `if (T x = f())`. The array work-around was the tipping point making me ask you whether the code was generated :) No harm intended. Cheers, thanks for answering the [tag:boost] tag!

Answer (score 0):

As the commented suggested you can catch the `out of range` error (system_error exception).

Or you can be more cautious and check first:

```
auto* param1 = json.as_object().if_contains("param1");
auto* param2 = json.as_object().if_contains("param2");
```

Likewise you can be more cautious about the string interpretation too:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd7d618a9f211b23)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void checkMessage(std::string msg) {
    auto json = boost::json::parse(msg);

    auto type   = json.at("type").as_string();
    auto* param1 = json.as_object().if_contains("param1");
    auto* param2 = json.as_object().if_contains("param2");
    auto* value1 = (param1? param1->if_string() : nullptr);
    auto* value2 = (param2? param2->if_string() : nullptr);

    std::cout << "Received: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "type:     " << type       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value1:   " << (value1 ? *value1 : "(MISSING)") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value2:   " << (value2 ? *value2 : "(MISSING)") << std::endl;
}

int main() {//
    checkMessage(R"({"type": "t1", "param1": "test parameter 1"})");
}
```

Printing

```
type:     "t1"
value1:   "test parameter 1"
value2:   "(MISSING)"
```