# gcc invokes constructor with std::initializer_list instead of copy elision while clang does not. Which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code snippet produces different results in different compilers:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo;

struct FooRef
{
    FooRef(Foo const &) { ::std::cout << "ref\n"; }
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { ::std::cout << "default\n"; }
    Foo(Foo const &) { ::std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    Foo(::std::initializer_list<FooRef>) { ::std::cout << "list\n"; }
};

Foo Make()
{
    return Foo{};
}

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto foo{Make()};
}
```

```
--std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

Reproducible with older standards and older compiler versions as well.

g++ 13

> default
> ref
> list

clang++ 15, vc++ 2022

> default

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAOykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma27BaWJ4AF7RAPq0eIP72CYaAILrm9uYewdOg8SYrHcPzye3y8Dh2ADFUKh9lYngDgaCIagAEqYKgAkxxGGPHY48GQlFUCCInZoBiDPZmABsMz2mJ2IBAg3QDLQXgIHzc%2BzcFLMPzRAFY3AxzGZobSACLouKStZYuEEYgg9mIqVY3F41AQGkYiz0xkEZkoBbsrlcnlYKhMLy0AgmQXCsyi2USgHqxFEyEkgTk8zU2m6hlMlnGjlmkVoRIATztQpFYoxkqebshEEDBoZR0cJ3OxCuN1tB0RBLu2rpacNrJNBzDjuut3tcedCalMrlT2JAFkmABrTBa1Wu3E/AiLBganXN2Ut9FPYLslhMYL92GYwc4u1WfkWBeRqIXLwMLxKdB2yX88U7K1EHb8KGYru9/vS6HTp4cOa0Tj83h%2BDhaUioJwnKWNYOwKAsSzvOsPCkAQmjvnM3axJSAB0AAcACclIYVwVJcPhGFoWsZjSJ%2BHCSD%2B8EAZwvAKCAGiwfBcxwLAMCIEaLCJHQ0TkJQaCcdxMTAFwaytFgABueDLAAangmAAO4APKJIwnAwTQNrRHREARFRETBPUkZqbw%2BnMMQkaKRE2iYA4xmkPxbCCIpDC0EZf68FgEReMAbhiLQdHcB5mALkY4juaQ%2BA/A4eDiZgAX/pgqg2WyKz/nOlRUdcETEIZHhYFRCp4CwxlzFQBjAAoskKcpqmBTIggiGI7BSPV8hKGoVG6K0BhGCg1jWPoeARHRkBzKgiTVAFAC0U1Mvs4qmCBlhmBoOxTQA6n5a3rYlCpMNtKnoIYjjILwqCxcQxB4FgI1am0NnVC4DDuJ4zT%2BM9kx9DErS5GkAgjC0SQpH9DCfSU/RjJUD0dEMjSvaM93RQInQNGD0xjLDAMDLDaMQ3M4GLMssz6F%2BlHhYBHA7KoaGUlNlKSDswDIMgOwiShXA7BAuCECQFKiTMvBwe5MyISA/IMWRFGkMV4ukL%2B/4U7R9GMcLpAsexxqJGyvEQPxXH0MQoSsCs1O0/TjPM6zazs7wmD4EQV3Mq0/ANaI4gtS7bUqOo4VdaQ8k5YkJUkxw35y1RFOKWyWvsqgVBUzTdMM0zLNsxzEAeAJBt81wAsq1oIukAgvxYDEd2S7wMsMfLZ00bYytCwXotrBhKFxNhcT8pIGj8l3lJEfyIdrGTCt14375q2x6sQEgeuCTrc8GygPXCZSGgMRJUmYFVSkqb%2B6l0AQWmULp4WmYZdnn%2BZlnWbZdUOYwBDOa5VGed5vm0P5dlYCFwBhf%2BkVoaxXirbJKyAUpUXSmRf8WUcrmTyqlQWV1iqBVKuVSqcld61XUrIRq7tpCe0UN7TqsR9CGGMP1Swg1hrwDGhNdI01ZoGnmotKwy1VobS2htXaOUDp22OlJM6F1HZxVoYjR6EBXBY1aIEYIvRwbfSBnkdI0ilEg1xoouw0NkaY3hoDLRSMag4zkVMCGthdFZH0cYooX1iYE0gsTMiYca7UUpqbJOJIV6s1QhoFCq0ub215tBPO49C5ITWNbCJUTokxJDlLKu4dyZ1zogxUJk94AzxAJrbWFBdaoCztEI2bBODuPNlsch3i/F%2BNtoEx2ehPZ4OagQ2QRCOq%2B1IQHJgQdUEh2cRHTgUcCAxx2HHBOZsGblKMJU3x/jM762iHzMwISmJzGLkwUulAPycHiWLau/SOBK1SSs0g4TIkxPOREoeI9a4HPzghEOZhrmuMFsci6qRnCSCAA%3D)

gcc seem to deduce object type to be `Foo` and selects priority constructor with `std::initializer_list` altering argument accordingly while other compilers just materialize prvalue.

Additional context: This problem arises in boost.json, `json` here is an (json) array in gcc and an (json) object in clang / vc.

```
::boost::json::value json{::boost::json::parse(R"({"param1": "foo", "param3": "bar"})")};
```

related question: [C++ How to check if json key exists using boost::json::value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724646/c-how-to-check-if-json-key-exists-using-boostjsonvalue/76724917)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'll assume C++17 or later.)

GCC is correct and Clang/MSVC are incorrect.

However, this is probably a defect in the standard. Initialization with braces of non-aggregate class types was missed in mandatory copy elision.

The rules for list-initialization, i.e. initialization with braces, are separated from non-list-initialization and the rules of list-initialization only contain a specific copy elision rule for aggregate types. Otherwise normal constructor overload resolution is used for class types and those will always prefer an `std::initializer_list` constructor. (And even if they would chose a copy/move constructor instead, it would still need to be called.)

See the open [CWG issue 2311](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2311.html).

If you use a non-braced initializer, i.e. `auto foo(Make());` or `auto foo = Make();`, instead of braced initialization, copy elision is allowed and mandatory.